Avoiding USA "gambling tax"
If I go to the USA on say Australian passport and win over $1200 then Uncle Sam keeps I think it is 30%.
If I go to the USA on say a UK passport and win over $1200 then Uncle Sam lets me keep it all.
Lets say I'm dual passport - Aus/Uk - but I reside and pay taxes etc in Aus. If I go to the USA and cross the border with my UK passport and win $1200.01 then I assume the casino will let me keep it (all they see is a UK passport).
Will the UK (or anyone else) come chasing me for a chunk of my winnings ?

"If I go to the USA on say a UK passport and win over $1200 then Uncle Sam lets me keep it all." On what basis? If a tax treaty, then that is only for people who are tax residents of the other country before coming to the US; it is not based on what passport you have.

@user102008 The casino will process the winnings based on what you claim and what documents you possess: if it's a UK passport, they'll accept your claim you're a UK resident.  This, however, does not absolve you of still needing to pay taxes yourself though.

@lambshaanxy: Presumably it's not just your passport -- I'm guessing you would have to sign some form swearing that you are a tax resident of some country (e.g. the UK).

I think the question is off-topic here. Tax regulations (and "tax optimization") are complex and not much related to travel (you pay taxes on income, wealth). Expat SE may ve slightly more relevant, but also... I do not think on topic. -- tax treaty are about not paying twice the taxes on same item (hindering international commerce), so information are exchanged. (and the line between simple mistake and taxation fraud )so a crime) is small, be careful and ask an expert on taxes, not random guys on Internet).

I rolled back the edit as only one kind of tax is really involved.

AFAIK only Australian tax residents who are professional gamblers need to declare winnings as income, but when/if you convert your US$ winnings to AUD it may be a capital gains tax event that you may have to declare.

@Willeke there's no such thing as gambling tax in the US, the question is about treaty provisions regarding tax withholding for income tax purposes.

@littleadv, it is clearly about a tax on the money won gambling, not normal income tax. And as a short term visitor.

@Willeke there is no "US gambling tax" per se. It's on how different countries treat foreign earnings, especially foreign earnings through gambling. Some countries tax gambling earnings through income tax, some through capital gains tax, some not at all. And with some of those countries the US has a treaty to handle tax collection, with some they don't and the resident would have to declare things themselves (and be guilty of tax evasion if they don't). Basically this question asks just that, how to help OP commit tax fraud.

@Willeke the situation is specific, maybe, but the answer is the same for any income. There's nothing special about gambling winnings in particular for this question.

This seems like something that might work because they will most likely check your passport and not ask for an electricity bill for instance to confirm you live in the UK. But this is basically tax evasion. The tax is based on where you live and not where you are a citizen of. If they find out, you may get fined or penalised in some way.

As mentioned in the comments, taxation is based on residency and source of income, not just citizenship. The US, as an exception to the rule, taxes its citizens regardless of physical presence rules, but most other countries don't.
So if you live in Australia, you wouldn't worry about the UK taxation even if you're a UK citizen. But it works both ways - you can't get UK tax discounts either.
You're asking about which treaty benefit is applicable to you when it comes to the US tax withholding on US sourced income. Note, withholding doesn't necessarily equate to taxes due.
The tax treaties in question are to resolve issues of double taxation, and are generally based on tax residency. Since you're the tax resident of Australia, the treaty relevant would be the US-Australian tax treaty. To explicitly clarify that, both the treaties (UK, Australia) start with:

Except as specifically provided herein, this Convention is applicable only to persons who are residents of one or both of the Contracting States.

It doesn't matter which passport you present at the immigration.

Will the UK (or anyone else) come chasing me for a chunk of my winnings ?

If the income is taxable in Australia then Australia will, most certainly, as they should, since you'd be committing tax evasion there. The US as well, since you'd be committing tax fraud in the US and depriving Uncle Sam from what is rightfully his. Both might also want a chunk of your freedom, since tax evasion and tax fraud are crimes punishable by jail time in both jurisdictions. All the three countries involved are known to be sharing a lot of information between them specifically directed at identifying financial crimes.

If I read between the lines, the casino staff would look at the passport (I assume they fill in  a form or something) and say "Hang on Mr UK Citizen - your passport says you live in Australia". I guess they also have your residential address from the ESTA (assuming you need one from the UK)

@John3136 the casino staff couldn't care less. The IRS, FinCEN, and their UK and Australian counterparts would be the ones to eventually cross check all these reports with the tax returns filed by their citizens. If you claim on W8-BEN UK tax treaty benefits, but don't file any UK tax return - the UK agency will start investigating. Very quickly the whole thing will unravel, since you're obviously not a very sophisticated criminal. All the countries involved know about all your other nationalities and their law enforcement is very tight with each other.

@John3136 Passports say nothing about your residency, neither Australian nor UK ones even have addresses.

@lambshaanxy Your are 100% correct. Nothing about residence (I found a scan of my passport to check :-). So I could get out of the casino with my $1200.01 but someone is going to want their share come tax time...

How is this answer affected by the fact that gambling winnings are not taxed in Australia?

@Doc I don't know what is taxed in Australia, but the source of income is the US - so they're first and foremost taxed in the US. If there's no tax and no reporting requirement then there's no evasion in Australia, but that doesn't remove the burden of taxation and correct reporting in the US.

OK, but your answer starts with a statement that taxation is based on residence and (potentially) citizenship. The OP is neither a resident nor citizen of the US, so what the US thinks isn't relevant?  The answer to this question is far more complex than you've made it out to be, and depends on factors including the exact type of gambling that was involved.  https://www.irs.gov/help/ita/as-a-nonresident-alien-are-my-gambling-winnings-exempt-from-federal-income-tax is a good place to start, but still only a fraction of the entire picture

For small wins in a casino (for example, you're at a blackjack table betting $25 a hand and eventually you're up $1,225), does anyone actually keep track of those winnings? My understanding is that such winnings are de facto not taxable because the casino doesn't keep track of them or report them to the IRS, and that gamblers almost never report them or pay taxes on them. I could be wrong, of course. (I will shamelessly say that I've had substantial gambling winnings and I've never reported any of them.)

"but most other countries don't", that's a bit of an understatement.  According to online sources, there is only one other country that taxes non-resident citizens - Eritrea.

@PeterM not even Eritrea, the tax situation there is a bit different. Ironically, Eritrea was denounced by the UN for that practice.

@littleadv Even including Eritrea, that means almost 99% of countries don't tax non-resident citizens.

@PeterM I know, I know... My experience is that the Americans on this (and the sister Money@SE) forum are very sensitive to being called out. Most of them don't realize how insane their country is when it comes to many different things, taxation included.

@user20574 actually many countries tax income sourced to them regardless of residency, that's why tax treaties exist to begin with. Most countries tax at source, and the US withholding mechanism exists to compensate for the lack of at source taxation.

@SophieSwett I would think that a casino that doesn't religiously track its payouts is a casino that won't be in business for long.

@Abion47 I'm not sure exactly why that would be the case. Casinos have been around for much longer than they've had the ability to track individual gamblers' gains and losses. In any case, regardless of what they track and don't track, the sources I've found all say that they don't report small wins to the IRS. So this answer's statement that the US will come chasing you seems to be incorrect. (Needless to say, I don't advise anyone to break the law... but it's interesting to note that the IRS seems to willingly turn a blind eye to small wins.)

@SophieSwett one time payouts of $600 or more have to be reported, so are cash transactions of $10K or more (e.g.: exchanging $10K for chips, or chips for $10K cash). The question assumes a reported transaction, so does the answer.

@littleadv That's a good point. I read "win over $1,200" and I was imagining several smaller wins totaling more than $1,200, but your interpretation makes more sense.

From a traveller's point of view:
There is no special gambling tax in the US. But there is a federal income tax, and also some states and cities have their own income tax.
Your winnings are presumed to be taxable income.
If you win less than $600, the hope is that you will follow the rules on your own.
If you win $600 or more, then generally the casino needs to issue you form W-2G. According to Instructions for Forms W-2G and 5754 (IRS.gov):

Foreign Persons
Payments of gambling winnings to a nonresident alien
individual or a foreign entity aren't subject to reporting or
withholding on Form W-2G. Generally, gambling winnings paid to a
foreign person are subject to 30% withholding under sections 1441(a)
and 1442(a) and are reportable on Form 1042, Annual Withholding Tax
Return for U.S. Source Income of Foreign Persons, and Form 1042-S,
Foreign Person's U.S. Source Income Subject to Withholding

Further, if you win $5000 or more, then the casino needs to withhold the estimated income tax of 28% or 31% of your winnings.
But please realize that this is just an estimate, and the actual tax calculation can be very complicated. Perhaps you owe no tax, because of some tax treaties, in which case you will need to ask for a refund. Or perhaps you will find that you owe even more income tax.

US 'regular' tax -- on residents as defined by IRC 7701 (which differs from residence for immigration in some cases) and also income of nonresidents 'effectively connected' to a US trade or business, is indeed complicated and withholding (when done at all) only an estimate. But the tax on nonresident non-'connected' income is much simpler -- no deductions, no credits, no brackets, just a flat rate depending only on type of income and residence of the person -- and withholding usually IS correct, at least if you fill out an appropriate W-8 form correctly. ...

... And this Q is based on the fact that for gambling winnings by a UK (tax) resident -- which the asker isn't really, but wants to pretend to be -- the flat rate is zero, thus no tax and no withholding.

My reading of IRS's guidance is that if he wins $1200 , which is over $600 and under $5000, then the casino needs to issue form W-2G, but he can still tell the casino not to withhold any estimated income tax, and doesn't need to explain why or prove anything to the casino.

Form W2G, and its dollar threshholds, only applies to US residents and entities (as defined by 7701). As your quote says quite plainly, W2G does not apply to nonresident individuals (actually only for non-'connected' income) and foreign entities; INSTEAD form 1042/S does. Your quote omits the rest of the paragraph which refers to Pub 515 (as the 1042S instructions also do) but see https://www.irs.gov/publications/p515#en_US_2024_publink1000225022 . Also resident withholding is now 24%; 28% and 31% were before TCJA in 2017.
